# Single Domain Controller Getting Event Errors 4013, 1844, 2886

Tags: active-directory, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, domaincontroller

I am trying to set up a new domain with only one domain controller.

My DNS role seems to be getting event warning 4013 and my Active Directory role is getting events 2886, 1844, 1463 and 614. I have tried just about everything I could search for and think of for getting rid of these errors. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It looks like I'm only receiving events 4013 and 2886 now. Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct, I will always get these 2 warnings occasionally since it is only a single domain controller on the domain hosting its own DNS service. These warnings do not seem to impede any performance on the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

For events 4013 you should not see this error at all, I run one domain controller with DNS also.  This is stating that you have an issue with the way DNS was configured.  You only see this if DNS has issues.  As for 2886 it has to do with LDAP you can ignore this event if you wish or you can make the changes to have the warning go away.

Check out this forum for help what 2886.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/57f4048a-2743-453f-93a3-765de01d0ad0